# bs4 can't recognize encoding python3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a few pages using Python3 for the first time. I have used Python2 many times with bs4 without any trouble, but I can't seem to be able to switch to python3, as I am always getting encoding errors.

For example, I am trying to scrape https://www.pgatour.com/webcom/tournaments/the-bahamas-great-exuma-classic/leaderboard.html

I have searched through a few threads here that have similar questions, without success.

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.pgatour.com/webcom/tournaments/the-bahamas-great-exuma-classic/leaderboard.html')
r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')
print(soup)
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xd7' in position 28935: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also tried to change `r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding` to `r.encoding = "utf-8"`, getting the same error.

Comment: Your code works for me. Also works without setting the encoding. Check that r.encoding is 'utf-8'

Comment: Before changing encoding, it is ISO-8859-1 and after, it is utf-8

Comment: Can you parse and print soup without changing the encoding?

Comment: No, if I remove r.encoding line, I get the same error.

Comment: Did you reinstall html5lib for python3?

Comment: For some reason, it works when I run it in terminal, but not using SublimeText ...

Comment: Path problem most likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the encoding as follows. This should fix your error.

```
r = requests.get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/beautifulsoup/cacao/index.html")
print(r.encoding)

soup = BS(r.content, 'html.parser').encode('utf-8')

print(soup)
```